# Is it good/advisable to increase metabolism and subsequently the temperature of the body through the consumption of selected food items during fever

Tags: metabolism, fever

Prior knowledge I have:

- Body heats up when there is higher than   normal metabolism.
- During a fever the body increases metabolism and there by the body temp to fight
- Certain food items increase body temperature, like eggs/protein

My Doubt:

- If the body is trying to increase the heat why not assist it through
  use of such food (garlic/eggs etc)
- Is it good for the body when we induce extra metabolism

Any resources/links/books/PDF is appreciated.
Please point out any mistakes in the prior knowledge and add points to the prior knowledge that are required for the logical deduction

Comment: Along with increased metabolism, your body usually produces more heat, but, normally, this will be lost quickly, because temperature regulation in a healthy person is quite efficient (by sweating, increased blood flow through the skin, etc.). It is true that the breakdown of proteins generates more heat than carbs and fats do, but, again, this will only slightly and temporarily increase your body temperature due to the same termoregulation, and will not likely solve any medical problem (infections, etc.); it may help to improve hypothermia, though.

Comment: I would seriously question the third assumption that "certain food items increase body temperature like eggs / garlic". Do you have any references for that?

Comment: I don't have any scientific basis for that. The only way I came to that conclusion is based on what I observed since childhood. The elderly in the family used to tell sleeping under the fan, eating eggs, etc to be "heat" (literally translated from local dialect in which it's called "ushna"), and I figured that they usually classified things under this if it required the body to do more work.

Comment: since the way the word "heat" is used is very ambiguous, consider this, anything that is said to be "heat" tends to have some similar effects on the body. For instance, developing redness in the eyes, burning sensation of the eyes, at times getting patches of boils on the face. Typically, to counter this "heat" effects few remedies are suggested called "tampu" translating to, you guessed it right, "cool". This includes a head bath with castor oil / eating "badam gond" and many others.  Now I really don't know how to look up the equivalent of these in terms of Western medicine. But they work